# how to draw scatter data with a hole into smooth contour plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymybo.jpg)
I have a set of data like this.[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/102iz5Dvqdw86KVIIkxPWNEbm9QZuc7go/view?usp=sharing)

matlab code is here.

```
Data = readmatrix("result_9_1.txt");
X = Data(:,1);
Y = Data(:,2);
Z = Data(:,3);

scatter(X,Y,50,Z);
xlim([-0.025,0.025]);
ylim([-0.025,0.025]);
colorbar;
```

Because there is a hole in the center, I have no good way to draw it in smooth contour plot.
If any advice, I am pleased to try. Thanks.

I have used tricontourf function, but the hole is covered by wrong colors.

Comment: First method: do not look at the colors inside the hole. Second method: erase the colors inside the hole. Third method: fille the hole with dummy data, such as the surrounding values.

Comment: Thanks, this way is not good enough. I want a better one.